# Appending to lists for each index in a range in python?

Tags: list, count, indexing, append, range

Mind you, I'm pretty pitiful at using Python, but what I am trying to do is append three lists (one for each Myro light sensor - left, center, right) a total of 15 times, each time after having the simulated robot turn a little bit. But for some reason it is not iterating the steps more than once.

Here's what I've got:

```
def rotations():
""" Moves robot 360 degrees, appending light values 15 times along the way."""
    arcs = 15
    lightLeftList = []
    lightCenterList = []
    lightRightList = []
    for count in range (1, arcs+1):
        turnRight(1/6.475/15)
        resultLeft = getLight("left")
        lightLeftList.append(resultLeft)
        resultCenter = getLight("center")
        lightCenterList.append(resultCenter)
        resultRight = getLight("right")
        lightRightList.append(resultRight)

    return lightLeftList, lightCenterList, lightRightList
```